# Странно работает аниматор юнити

Tags: c#, unity3d, анимация

Аниматор юнити странно работает. Когда создаю анимацию руки, например рука должна повернуться по X с 30 до 25 то юнити вместо того чтобы пойти 30,29,28..25 идет 30,50,120..360,25.Из-за этого анимация смотриться очень криво, кто знает почему так?

И Ещё хорошо ли анимировать в юнити, или лучше же в блендере либо в какой-нибудь другой программе?

Answer (score 0):

Стандартный аниматор Unity имеет некоторые проблемы. Т.к. у тебя анимация руки, то могу посоветовать бесплатный плагин для костной анимации:

> https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/animation/umotion-community-animation-editor-95986

Либо можешь использовать другой плагин. В Unity Store из много